# No HTML o que é um Checkbox Indeterminado e como usar esse status junto com o CSS?

Tags: html, css, input, checkbox

Até onde eu sabia um `input` do tipo `Checkbox` poderia ter três estados, *checado*, *não checado* e *desabilitado*. Mas parece que ele tem um quarto estado que é o ***indeterminado***.

Veja na imagem um comparativo dos estados que o `checkbox` pode assumir em browser diferentes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é, como é possível setar um `checkbox` como indeterminado, visto que diferente do atributo `checked` o atributo "*`undetermined`*" não existe...

Gostaria de poder usar um `<input type="checkbox" undetermined name="" id="">` mas isso não funcionou...

**Exemplo:** Reparei que no CSS tenho como estilizar elementos de acordo com o estado do checkbox, como eu faria para estilizar a `<label>` caso o `checkbox` seja `indeterminado`?

Teste com código:

```css
[type="checkbox"] + label {
 color: blue;
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
 color: green;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  name="" id=""> 
<label>normal </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" checked name="" id=""> 
<label>checado </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" undetermined name="" id=""> 
<label>indeterminado </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" disabled name="" id=""> 
<label>desabilitado </label>
<br>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### *como é possível setar um checkbox como indeterminado?*

Esse estado é definido por uma propriedade do *checkbox*, que é `indeterminate`, que só pode ser acessada usando `javascript`:

> há um terceiro estado em que uma caixa de seleção pode estar:
>   indeterminada. Este é um estado em que é impossível dizer se o item
>   está ativado ou desativado. Isso é definido usando a
>   indeterminate propriedade do objeto HTMLInputElement via JavaScript
>   (não pode ser definido usando um atributo HTML)

Fonte: [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox)

### *Gostaria de poder usar um  mas isso não funcionou*

Sim, por causa da razão acima, esse atributo só pode ser acessado via `javascript`, portanto, diferente de outro atributos como `readonly` ou `disabled` por exemplo, não pode ser definido na tag.
Aqui um exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('i1').indeterminate = true;
```

```css
input:indeterminate + label {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
   <input id="i1" type="checkbox" /> <label>Indeterminated</label>
</p>
<p>
   <input id="i2" type="checkbox" />
</p>
```

Pode ser estilizado usando o *pseudoclass* `:indeterminate`, como no exemplo acima.
Fonte [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:indeterminate)

Só para esclarecer, independe da aparência de como ele é renderizado em cada motor, ele pode estar "checked" ou não, e permanecer igual, conforme esse outro exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('i1').indeterminate = true;
document.getElementById('i2').indeterminate = true;
document.getElementById('i2').checked = true;

console.log('i1.checked=' + document.getElementById('i1').checked);
console.log('i2.checked=' + document.getElementById('i2').checked);
```

```html
<p>
   <input id='i1' type='checkbox'  />
</p>
<p>
   <input id='i2' type='checkbox'  />
</p>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas!

Answer (score 10):

De fato, não existe a propriedade `indeterminate` que faz o *checkbox* entrar no estado indeterminado, isso **porque não é um estado**. O `indeterminate` é meramente visual.

Os estados possíveis de um *checkbox* são apenas *true* ou *false* (*on* ou *off*, 1 ou 0, ou qualquer variação equivalente). O campo `indeterminate` é apenas uma ferramenta para o *web developer* indicar ao usuário que os dados que a aplicação recebeu são insuficientes para aferir o real estado do campo.

**Exemplo**: dados de uma publicação de um produto em algum *marketplace*. Há na tela um *checkbox* que define se o produto está publicado ou não na ferramenta externa. O estado real do campo é definido através de uma chamada à API do *marketplace*, porém a chamada falha, por qualquer motivo. A **aplicação será incapaz de definir se o produto está, ou não, publicado** e qualquer estado que seja colocado no *checkbox* poderia confundir o usuário, então usa-se o *pseudo-estado* `indeterminate`.

A única forma de definir um campo *checkbox* como indeterminado é através do JavaScript, com `elemento.indeterminate = true`.

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]')
checkbox.indeterminate = true;

console.log(checkbox.checked);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```

Conforme a especificação [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#checkbox-state-(type=checkbox)), o *pseudo-estado* `indeterminate` é apenas **visual** e não sobrescreve o estado atual do campo.

> *The control is never a true tri-state control, even if the element's indeterminate IDL attribute is set to true. The indeterminate IDL attribute only gives the appearance of a third state.*

Por isso que os estados são apenas *true* ou *false*. Veja que no exemplo acima é dado que o campo não está selecionado, mas se adicionar a propriedade *checked*, o retorno muda, independente se é indeterminado ou não.

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]')
checkbox.indeterminate = true;

console.log(checkbox.checked);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

O formulário sendo submetido, o valor enviado pelo navegador será o definido pela propriedade *checked*, indiferente se o campo é indeterminado ou não. No primeiro exemplo o navegador iria submeter o campo como *false* enquanto no segundo como *true*.

Se for requisito da aplicação não submeter campos indeterminados para evitar qualquer tipo conflito entre os dados, a lógica de validação deverá ocorrer exclusivamente no lado do cliente, com JavaScript. O servidor não terá como saber se o campo foi submetido como indeterminado ou não. Uma forma de auxiliar o usuário é aplicando um estilo com CSS nos campos indeterminados utilizando `:indeterminate`:

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]')
checkbox.indeterminate = true;
```

```css
:indeterminate + label {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<label>Publicado?</label>
```

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro como usar esse pseudo-estado! Obrigado